# (XCODE) ERROR: ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I know this is a very common error, but I believe I have tried every single solution I have seen already posted. I use Unity for my app and do not know much about xcode syntax. I also believe it might be coming from UnityAds but I do not know how to address it. Thank you very much for any and all help.
[image]

The full error is as follows:

```
duplicate symbol _UnityAdsMakeStringCopy in:
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-AB557C98F189FEA5.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapper in:
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-AB557C98F189FEA5.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapper in:
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-AB557C98F189FEA5.o
duplicate symbol _UnityAdsCreateNSString in:
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-AB557C98F189FEA5.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapper._gameId in:
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/Ryan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-esxzrgjuyrqyrrdacqkggcjbgupy/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-AB557C98F189FEA5.o
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

NOTE:

Bitcode is set to NO (that was a proposed solution from another question)

Comment: I have few questions for you. What Unity version? What Xcode version? Did you create the project or did you get it from somewhere else? Plugins usually cause problems like this. What plugins are you using?List them. These are very important things to provide in your question to even get help.

Comment: 5.3.4 I think for unity (most recent), 7.3.1 xcode, I created the project, I am using only Unity Ads and I think In-App purchases but I have not implemented an in-app purchase

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I've the similar problem, if you've solved, can you share?

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak I can try to help you out here but I do not specifically remember the fix. Try Deleting the DerivedData of the Xcode project.